# Javascript in language other than english

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();
document.write(d);
```

What will it print. It normally prints time of local machine. Will it print time in French language if machine's language is French?
Or is JavaScript outputs just in English?

Comment: Maybe you want [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of all `Date.prototype.to*String` methods are implementation-dependant (a la [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) in section 15.9). They are however based on an ISO representation which is in English. So basically, the default is always English. When it comes to `Date.prototype.toLocale*String` methods the standards say the string should be one that

> corresponds to the conventions of the host environment‘s current
>   locale

However there are still some implementation differences:

In FF 4:
`Date.prototype.toLocaleString()`  [uses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) the OS settings.
`Date.prototype.toString()`  is *[always](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString)* in [American] English.

[image: FF uses local settings]

While in Chrome 14:
Both are always English. This has already [been noticed](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29779&q=tolocalestring&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Pri%20Area%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Modified%20Owner%20Mstone%20OS).

[image: Chrome always English]

Test for yourselves: http://jsfiddle.net/USJeE/

Comment: Hey Davin, W3Schools states "The toLocaleString() method is supported in all major browsers, except Google Chrome." So this is not a surprise. Thats why i've suggested some key-value function to get the needed values.

Comment: @Shai, that is one way of doing it, although it won't localise the format entirely.

Comment: Of course :) The problem is there isn't really a cross-browser way to get that data unfortunately. And you can't ignore Chrome in your web-apps, of course. since its a rising force. Usually people looking to localize dates to a specific language develop the app in that specific language, and string-replacement would work well. For multi-lingual apps, developers would usually use language files, i guess :)

Comment: @davin thanks for the screenshots, thats exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will output the date in english usually, as far as i'm aware.

You could build your own small library to rename English day names to French day name, so as with months, etc...

You could also try and use [toLocaleString](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) but i'm not sure it would do the job. I think it would be easier to implement your own set of "replacement" strings.

Shai.